# show background image on td tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show the background image on tag td. and I have code

```
<td style="background-image:url(../uploadimages/18-2-2013-23-33-01-Lighthouse.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:250px 180px;"></td>

<img src="../uploadimages/18-2-2013-23-33-01-Lighthouse.jpg" />
```

I test the path by using tag img and it get correct the path but I do not know it's not show in the background image on td tag.

thankyou very much

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `td` won't show a background image because it hasn't got any content, hence there's no  space in the `td` to draw the background. The `background-size` sets the *size of the background*, not the size of the container. Try `width:250px;height:180px;` in the inline style for the `td` - it should show the image.

[Here's a demonstration in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gHYsh/1/). If you remove the `width` and `height` settings from the CSS you won't see the image.

Answer (score 9):

**Proper Solution**

First of all, you have to specify the width and height of td. Follow the example that will work properly---

```
<td style="background-image:url(../uploadimages/18-2-2013-23-33-01-Lighthouse.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:250px 180px;   width: 250px; height: 180px;"></td>
```

Comment: Did you just basically reword the accepted solution ?